# Partition array in sub-arrays using zero-crossings as selection boundaries

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, slice

I have a 2D array where one row contains the measurement of a force, and other rows contain other measurement values.

I want a way to get subarrays consisting of slices in the format `subarray = full_array[:,start:end]`, where start and end are zero-crossings.

For example, and ignoring remaining rows, an array with first row `[-2, -1, 1, 2, 4, -1, -3, 2, 5, 8, 9, -3]` would be extracted like this:

```
extractions[0] = [1, 2, 4]
extractions[1] = [2, 5, 8, 9]
```

It's conceptually similar to "blob detection", but only along one axis.

I cannot figure a way to do it cleanly using Numpy or Scipy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach -

```
# Mask of greater than zeros
mask = np.r_[False, arr>0, False]

# Nonzero island start and stop indices
idx = np.flatnonzero(np.diff(mask)).reshape(-1,2)

# Split array based on start, stop indices
out = [arr[i:j] for i,j in idx]
```

For performance, use `mask[1:] != mask[:-1]` in place of `np.diff(mask)` and `np.concatenate` could replace `np.r_`.

Sample run -

```
In [332]: arr
Out[332]: array([-2, -1,  1,  2,  4, -1, -3,  2,  5,  8,  9, -3])

In [333]: out
Out[333]: [array([1, 2, 4]), array([2, 5, 8, 9])]
```